# What is the recommended way of deleting a user account from Google Identity Toolkit (Gitkit)?

Tags: java, user-accounts, google-identity-toolkit

I did not find guidance on deleting the user accounts from Gitkit database in the documentation. I was planning on creating some test accounts based on different providers as well as some password based accounts. What is the best way to clear all these test accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Identity Toolkit Java client library](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-java-client/) provides the [deleteUser()](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/identitytoolkit/GitkitClient.java#L404) method to delete an individual user account:

```
GitkitClient gitkitClient = GitkitClient.newBuilder()
      .setGoogleClientId("your-oauth2-web-client-id-at-Google")
      .setServiceAccountEmail("your-service-account-email-at-Google-developer-console")
      .setKeyStream(new FileInputStream("path-to-your-service-account-private-file"))
      .build();
gitkitClient.deleteUser("test-user-id");
```

You may want to create a test project to try the deletion (and other operations), since deleted accounts can not be recovered.

Comment: Thanks! Yup, I had ultimately found it among the methods available for GitkitClient.